# Mixpanel img href tracking not working

Tags: javascript, html, mixpanel, event-tracking

I've a hyperlink image that I'd like to be tracked by Mixpanel, but it's not seemed to be picked up by Mixpanel.

Here is the html

```
<div class = "discounts">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="/static/m1/images/google.png" alt="Google"></a>
    </div>
```

Here is the mixpanel js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    mixpanel.track_links(".discounts a", "Google Logo", {"referrer": document.referrer});
</script>
```

I've no idea why the event is not getting registered on Mixpanel.

Please help.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console? Are you calling `mixpanel.init` ?

Comment: This is what I see on browser console Uncaught ReferenceError: mixpanel is not defined

Comment: You have to actually include the mixpanel script for this to work... https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript

Comment: I've the mixpanel script on the website, not to mention I also have other events that are properly being tracked by Mixpanel

Comment: Your error is pretty clean cut.. Maybe you put this script tag before the mixpanel one? Hard to say without seeing the rest of your HTML.

Comment: Yup, I made the mistake of putting the script before the mixpanel one! Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it. You can put it as an answer and I can tick mark it.